# Scrollbar missing in iOS app

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, scrolling

When scrolling a question or its answers in the iOS app, the scroll bar doesn't appear.

iOS 7.1
SE App 0.1.60

#### Reasoning

As requested by Ben, some persuasion for having scroll bars:

- They've been standard for decades
- They're entirely unobtrusive considering they disappear when you're not actively scrolling
- They exist everywhere else in the app: feed, inbox, questions, search, tags, users, profile, sidebar, ask
- The purpose of scroll bars: they show you your position in the view

I'd love to hear the reasoning why it was deliberately eschewed in just these two views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're back.

I think "by design" was folklore, related to the fact Android doesn't have them. Unless they're causing some terrible problem, there's no reason not to have them.

Answer (score 2):

We kinda did this on purpose, but if you think this is a problem, let us know your reasoning.  We're open to persuasion.

Comment: I vote no scrollbars, not needed :-)

Comment: I guess where I'm struggling is how it would be somehow better usability to *not* have them